# Test for a syntactically correct path

Tags: .net, filepath, string-matching

In .NET is there a function that tests if a string is syntactically a correct path? I specifically don't want it to test if the path actually exists.

my current take on this is a regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]:|\\)?\\?([^/\\:*?"<>|]+[/\\])*[^/\\:*?"<>|]*
```

matches:

```
c:\
bbbb
\\bob/john\
..\..\
```

rejects:

```
xy:
c:\\bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just using a regex for this since you specifically don't want to test if the path exists.

Here's something [google helped me dig up](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=425):

```
RegEx="^([a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)(\\[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)+(\.[^\/\\:*?"<>|]+)$"
```

You could combine this with System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars() method and make the regex dynamically exclude all of the invalid characters.

Comment: WT.. is that escaped for? I'm not able to make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path) will throw an exception if it is not a syntactically correct path without checking to see if it exists.

Comment: If that works, nice, but the fail case is just as valid for me as the pass case do I'd rather not throw/catch.

Comment: Yeah, could be what is needed.  Here's the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx  
From the article,"However, if path does exist, the caller must have permission to obtain path information for path." Could throw a wrench in depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use System.IO.Path and the GetInvalidPathChars() function?